# Does AAOS (Android Automotive OS) supports VSOCK communication to transmit data between VMs?

Tags: android-automotive

I am looking for APIs which I can use for writing android service to receive/transmit data while AAOS is running as a VM with another Ubuntu-VM.
The Ubuntu-VM already has native support for **[virtio-VSOCK](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/vsock.7.html)**

Is there similar implementation exiting in AAOS?

Not tried anything on AAOS but a quick look on internet does not give any result about AAOS supporting virtio-vscok !!

Answer (score 0):

Is the question primarily about virtio or vsock? If you're looking for just a general-purpose connection over vsock, you can use [RPC Binder over vsock](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/native/libs/binder/include/binder/RpcServer.h;l=86;drc=dfb9218b34625b1639d28910848a5c206163cbab), but Linux support is quite bleeding edge - you'd need to compile libbinder by yourself on Ubuntu (i.e. write make files).

Another alternative is gRPC which just recently [added vsock support](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/32738).